# Rewrite MySQL query using Codeigniter Active record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have started CodeIgniter not long ago. Can some tell me how to rewrite this query

```
SELECT question.timestamp AS question_time, reply.timestamp AS reply_time, 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(reply_time, question_time)) AS time_used_to_reply 
FROM question JOIN reply ON question.id = reply.question_id WHERE question.company_id=someid
```

using the  activerecord

Also any tutorial to quickly understand  activerecord would be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many researches, I ended up writing my own active record script.

```
$this->db->select(array('DATEDIFF(reply.timestamp, question.timestamp)'))
    ->from('question')
    ->join('reply', 'question.id = reply.question_id')
    ->where('question.company_id', $company_id);
```

Thanks